When ask Image getting iOS permission once user didn't allowed the permission how to ask again to allow the permission
once user want to change the profile , but user didn't allowed the permission once user didn't
allowed the permission , how to ask every time the permission when user want change the profile (only when user didn't allowed the permission) Flutter on Ios
user must allow the permission

You can go into the Settings > [AppName] and various permissions show up there, and you can flip them there.

Try below code with a package permission_handler to manage permissions.
    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      checkPermission();
    }
    
    Future<void> getImage() async {
      PermissionStatus status = await Permission.photos.status;
      if (status.isGranted) {
        // Proceed to pick an image
      } else {
        await requestPermission();
      }
    }

Check the current status of the permission with below method.
    Future<void> checkPermission() async {
      PermissionStatus status = await Permission.photos.status;
    
      if (status.isDenied) {
        // Permission is denied, show a dialog or message to the user
      } else if (status.isGranted) {
        // Permission is granted, proceed with accessing images
      }
    }

If permission is denied,show a dialog explaining why the permission is necessary and how to enable it.
    void showPermissionDialog(BuildContext context) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Permission Required'),
            content: Text('This app needs permission to access your photos. Please enable it in settings.'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                child: Text('Open Settings'),
                onPressed: () {
                  openAppSettings();
                },
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: Text('Cancel'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );

If user initially denies the permission but has not permanently denied it, you can request the permission again with below method.
    Future<void> requestPermission() async {
      PermissionStatus status = await Permission.photos.request();
    
      if (status.isGranted) {
        // Permission granted, proceed with accessing images
      } else if (status.isDenied) {
        // Permission still denied, show a dialog
        showPermissionDialog(context);
      } else if (status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
        // Permission is permanently denied
        showPermissionDialog(context);
      }
    }


